# Casting ArrayList class variables for deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a single variable in java however seem to be bumping into a problem when casting the value:

```
public void loadGrid(Sudoku testGrid) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\tmp\\grid.grd");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        testGrid.sudokuGrid = (Sudoku.sudokuGrid) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
    } catch(IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sudoku is a class containing an ArrayList of ArrayList variable.
I run into:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Sudoku.sudokuGrid cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: So, shouldn't the cast be to something like `(List<ArrayList<?>>) in.readObject();` ?

Comment: Do you have any class within Sudoku named sudokuGrid?

Comment: Yes, what is sudokuGrid? a field in class Sudoku? casts are types, not variables. What are you trying to do?

Comment: SudokuGrid is the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast to the type of `Sudoku.sudokuGrid`, not the `sudokuGrid` field itself:

```
testGrid.sudokuGrid = (ArrayList<ArrayList<SomeType>>) in.readObject();
```